# Whats the best place to get the Layout Height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set `Padding Top` to Specified `View` from another `Layout Height`, but the the `Layout` keeps giving me `0` value.
I've tried to put the code in `onCreate` and `onStart` and `onResume` its the same value.

Sample of the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_layout);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText.setPadding(0, findViewById(R.id.main_screen_banner_linearLayout).getBottom(), 0, 0);

        System.err.println("Bottom:" + findViewById(R.id.main_screen_banner_linearLayout).getHeight() + "");
    }
}
```

================
Regarding for C Nick Answer:

thanks for @C Nick 
i made a solution by his answer:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (runnable != null) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    }
}
```

and `onCreate` in `Activity`

```
    final CustomTextView customTextView = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    customTextView.setRunnable(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Height:" + findViewById(R.id.main_screen_banner_linearLayout).getHeight());
            customTextView.setPadding(customTextView.getPaddingLeft(),
                    findViewById(R.id.main_screen_banner_linearLayout).getHeight(),
                    customTextView.getPaddingRight(), customTextView.getPaddingBottom());
        }
    });
```

and now it works fine, but i dont think my solution is optima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the padding sometime after the layout pass occurs.  You can probobly override the onLayout of your EditText, and there set the padding because the View should be layed out and measured by then.

This is a decent resource for the layout/measure/draw workflow.

[How Android Draws](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)